# Semantic issue for AuthChallengeDisposition enum in Swift-generated bridging header

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, bridging-header, objc-bridging-header

I'm adding `URLSessionDelegate` protocol conformance to one of my Swift classes (called `SearchViewController`), and I'm implementing [urlSession(_:task:didReceive:completionHandler:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskdelegate/1411595-urlsession). The signature of this method includes the type `URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition`. When I build the project, it appears that this type causes issues in the automatically generated Swift-Objective C header:

[image: The compile error.]

It seems unlikely that the Swift team messed up the bridging behavior since I haven't been able to turn up anything through searching (and other people are presumably implementing and bridging this delegate method), but I don't know what else could be going on. I know next to nothing about these bridging headers, so I'm pretty lost here.

Comment: Can you give us some code instead of a picture (i.e. try to provide a [mcve])?

Comment: @Cristik I included the picture to show the problematic section of the automatically generated header along with the compiler error that Xcode was spitting out. The relevant code is just an extension of `SearchViewController` declaring conformance to `URLSessionDelegate` and, inside the extension, the implementation of the function in question (the implementation details aren't relevant and have no bearing on whether the issue occurs).